# Select on top magento

Tags: magento

I'm new to magento. I need to implement Select box on top of site. It must be on every page. Depends on that select on product page will change additional information so people can choose if they like metric or imperial. You can see product page:

http://www.vetus.com/boat-windows/portholes/vetus-porthole-aluminium-category-a-iii-incl-mosquito-screen-8063.html

Thanks for help! Sorry for grammar mistakes.

Comment: When you say "It must be on every page" do you mean all product pages ??

Comment: @Munjal I mean every page on site, like languages select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way doing this would be to create two different store views (metric and imperial) this will serve your purpose without involving into too much of programming.

However you could well do this using sessions.

Comment: Store views is for languages, but anyway, thank you!